# Show that $f$ is continuous if is $BV$ and has the ivp.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f \colon [a,b] \to {R}$ has the intermediate value property in $[a,b]$ and $f$ is of bounded variation, then $f$ is continuous.

I know that if $f$ is $BV$ then is bounded and $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$ where $g$ and $h$ are increasing functions, so for all $c$ in $[a,b]$ there exists the one-sided limits. Also I know that $f$ is continuous if and only if $V_{f}$ is continuous, while $f$ is $BV$, so I could show that $V_{f}$ is continuous, knowing that this is increasing.

Comment: Maybe you can show $V_f$ has the intermediate value property : an increasing function with ivp is continuous

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $c \in (a, b)$. Let $\alpha=lim_{t \rightarrow c^-} f(t)$ and $\beta=lim_{t \rightarrow c^+} f(t)$. Suppose $\alpha < \beta$. Then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $t_1 \in (c - \delta, c)$ implies $|f(t_1) - \alpha| < \frac{\beta - \alpha}{3}$ and $t_2 \in (c, c + \delta)$ implies $|f(t_2) - \beta| < \frac{\beta - \alpha}{3}$. Suppose $t_1$ and $t_2$ are chosen so that $\frac{f(t_1) + f(t_2)}{2} \neq f(c)$. Then, from the IVP, there is some $t \in (t_1, t_2)$ such that $f(t)=\frac{f(t_1) + f(t_2)}{2}$, a contradiction.

The other kinds of discontinuities can be treated similarly.

Comment: There is no discontinuity of other kind as $f$ is of bounded variation.+1

Comment: Indeed. Actually what I meant was the cases where $\alpha > \beta$ and $\alpha = \beta \neq f(c)$.